# for-each or create new object(instance) what is better to use in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

can you please tell me what is better to use?

1. for-each loop
2. create new object of class.

In mine case both aspect gave me same output.
so, my question is that what will i prefer to use.

**If i choose 1st aspect.**

whenever my page load at that time in fore-each loop(50 record fixed) will come.
and every time that loop execute so, my page execution is bit slower.

**If i choose 2nd aspect**

whenever my page load at that time new object is created and memory initialize

In asp.net mvc any inbuilt function or method to remove garbage collection(collection of unusual object) ?

please tell me what would i prefer for better use with relevant reason.

Comment: What now? Java or c#?

Comment: my question is related to only c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write whichever one is simpler to code and more obviously correct. Then, see if your page is too slow or uses too much memory. (You get to decide what "too slow" or "too much" means, it's your application!)

If it works, great! Your problem is solved, work on adding more value to your application in some other way.

If it is too slow or uses too much memory, then try the less simple approach.

Then -- and this is the important part -- **measure** the difference **for your application**. Then, and only then, can you know the right answer.

Comment: Hello Mr. Daniel Pryden   thank you for your response.